# Error on creating first Hello world application using Spring mvc

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

First of all, I want to apologize for maybe duplicate topic but I couldn't find the answer to my question.

I started today with spring mvc and i have some issues with my "hello world" application. Can anyone help me make this program to work? Because i have followed some instructions and i have no clue how to solve this.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYXST.jpg) is my project structure

[image]

HelloController class

```
package com.pluralsight.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


@Controller
public class HelloController {

       @RequestMapping(value="/greeting.html")
       public String sayHello(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("greeting","Hello world");

        return "hello";
      }    
  }
```

hello.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
     <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>    
     <h1>${greeting}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

servlet-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pluralsight.controller"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" 
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp"></bean>

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- 1.create servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <!-- 1.1 we need a servlet name -->
        <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
        <!-- 1.2 we need a servlet class -->
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <!-- 1.3 we need to specify the configuration file (default) -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <!-- 2.servlet mapping -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

and full stacktrace

```
Apr 08, 2014 8:30:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;D:\app\Laura\product\12.1.0\dbhome_2\bin;D:\app\LauraPC\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\apache-1.9.3\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\javac\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Users\Laura\android-sdks\tools\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;.
    Apr 08, 2014 8:30:17 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
    WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:FitTracker' did not find a matching property.
    Apr 08, 2014 8:30:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    Apr 08, 2014 8:30:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    Apr 08, 2014 8:30:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    INFO: Initialization processed in 606 ms
    Apr 08, 2014 8:30:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    INFO: Starting service Catalina
    Apr 08, 2014 8:30:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
    Apr 08, 2014 8:30:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
    Apr 08, 2014 8:30:19 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    Apr 08, 2014 8:30:19 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    Apr 08, 2014 8:30:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in 1225 ms
    Apr 08, 2014 8:30:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'fitTrackerServlet'
    Apr 08, 2014 8:30:52 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
    INFO: FrameworkServlet 'fitTrackerServlet': initialization started
    Apr 08, 2014 8:30:52 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
    INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'fitTrackerServlet-servlet': startup date [Tue Apr 08 20:30:52 EEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
    Apr 08, 2014 8:30:52 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
    INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml]
    Apr 08, 2014 8:30:52 PM org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider registerDefaultFilters
    INFO: JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
    Apr 08, 2014 8:30:52 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
    SEVERE: Context initialization failed
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:52)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:101)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:76)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:298)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:153)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:130)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:285)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:223)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:598)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:661)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:517)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:865)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    Apr 08, 2014 8:30:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:52)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:101)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:76)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:298)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:153)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:130)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:285)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:223)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:598)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:661)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:517)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:865)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    Apr 08, 2014 8:30:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
    SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet fitTrackerServlet
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:52)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:101)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:76)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:298)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:153)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:130)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:285)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:223)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:598)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:661)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:517)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:865)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Which Spring version are you using? Which Java version are you using?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am using Spring 3.5.0 and Java 8

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `ClassReader` class constructor shown in your stack trace has a piece of code commented in version 4+ (in other words, it's there in version 3)

```
// checks the class version
/* SPRING PATCH: REMOVED FOR JDK 1.8 BYTECODE COMPATIBILITY
if (readShort(off + 6) > Opcodes.V1_7) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
*/
```

Basically, you can't use Java 8 with Spring 3 (there is no Spring 3.5.0). Upgrade to Spring 4 or downgrade to Java 7.

Comment: I meant Spring tool suite 3.5.0

Comment: @laura If you open up your `pom.xml`, what version are the Spring dependendies?

Comment: `<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
     <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>'

Comment: @laura Ok that's what I was looking for, 3.2.0.RELEASE. You simply have incompatible versions of Java versus Spring. You options are as I stated in my answer.

Comment: Thank you! I will use Java 7 for now on

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same problem using the sample project from https://github.com/cheptsov/SpringMVCApp and changed the Spring Framework version to

```
<spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
```

in the **pom.xml**.