# Spring ContextConfiguraion failed to load Application Context

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a very simple test, like so:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = testing.class)
public class test {

    @Autowired
    public String str;

    @Test
    public void works(){
        assertNotNull(str);
    }
}
```

The configuration for this class is:

```
@Configuration
public class testing {

    @Bean
    public String getString(){
        return "hi";
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
    2015-10-02 14:18:23,761 ERROR [main] [test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance()] - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@4df828d7] to prepare test instance [com.glassdoor.search.jobs.spring.test@b59d31]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:313)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.
```

I'm using Maven, and this code fails on the command line and from the IDE (intelli-j). Can anyone illuminate for me what could be going wrong?

Comment: put more details about your question and explain more your problem

Comment: These are all the details I have. What else can I provide?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944716/error-on-creating-first-hello-world-application-using-spring-mvc

Comment: None of those solutions helped out. :(

Comment: Post your pom.xml  Maybe a mix of Spring versions?

Comment: Ah, the issue was the there were apparently conflicting versions of spring that caused the issue. Round everything out to the latest release of spring 3, and everything works fine now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tested your code with this `pom.xml` it worked fine, so we'd need to see your pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.xenoterracide</groupId>
<artifactId>so1</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>
```

I've also tested on Spring 3

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.xenoterracide</groupId>
<artifactId>so1</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.14.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.14.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.14.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.14.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should check if you're using proper Spring version, e.g. Spring 3.x does not support Java 8.

Comment: this is only sort of true we are using Spring 3 on Java 8 at work, it only blows up when you try to use a lambda or method reference. I am in the process of migrating now.

Comment: Well, it seems that is not true, because I set up environment to check this failing test from the question, with Java 8 and Spring 3.x and it failed :). So I think that it can be said, that Spring 3.x does not (fully) support Java 8.

Comment: this is not an answer, it shall be comment to the question.

Comment: it would be correct to say that it does not fully support (or I believe we found "best effort" only).

Comment: @DariuszJanicki updated my answer, I'm running java 8, turns out the tests work on Spring 3 as well... so...